# Cannot attach files Custom SharePoint List 2007

Tags: 2007, list, custom

I have customized the newitem.aspx.

The Attach button was not working at beginning, I add this code (following KB) and the button started to work.

But then it actually shows the window where I can browse and select the document but when I click on ok it does nothing.

```
<xsl:template name="dvt_1">
      <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">ListForm</xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
      <table border="0" width="100%">
           <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
               <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
           </xsl:call-template>
       </table>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: this is the code I had remplace in my page:

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing some parts which must also be added - these are actually all detailed at the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953271/en-us?p=1

I've been through the same steps in the past, i can guarantee it works!

Comment: No haven´t....

Well I tried to Install the update but got an error message "Product version is not the expected" Then when I look for "<xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">" it was not in my page.